# Is there any solution to populate data into to the Redis from external database #redis

Tags: caching, redis, external, connectivity

**Is there any solution to bootstrap redis with data from external database.**

**Want to achieve:** While bringing up redis instances data should be populated from the external Database.
So after the redis server is up and ready what ever the data on the database should be available on the redis as well.

any ideas?

**Redis Cluster details:**
Deployment type: Sentiel Redis
Redis version : 5.0.3
Platform: Kubernetes (1.20.0)
Storage : PVC

Comment: It depends on your database. Also there are some related questions about syncing Redis and DB: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807578/what-is-the-best-strategy-to-sync-data-between-db-and-redis-cache

Comment: The requirement is more like bootstrapping redis, i.e. while starting redis server, it should come up with a given set of data, which is available in an a external database.